# Passing Values from a RefEdit Control in a Userform to a Variant Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

I am attempting to pass a range from a RefEdit control in a userform to an array in VBA using statements like:

```
y0 = Range(RefEdit1.value)
```

I thought by using the `.Value` property, this would exclude formatting from whatever selection the user made in RefEdit1 and just the raw, unformatted values would be stored in y0. However, this is NOT happening: When I test it and select a range with currency values, the formatting is stored in y0 and, of course, is problematic for future calculations.

I even tried this:

```
y0 = Range(RefEdit1.value).value
```

But that did not work either. Any assistance is appreciated.

## ===============================

Thank you for your response. See the screenshots below. The numeric values with the currency format in M2:M21 are selected using RefEdit1. Notice the actual value printed in the function bar (highlighted in the red box): These are the values that I want to store in y0 (the raw, unformatted, UNROUNDED values):

[image]

Here is the code:

[image]

And here are the values that are printed to P35:

[image]

Not only has it retained the unwanted formatting, it has rounded the values. Any ideas? IMPORTANT: It is a standard feature of this particular application that the user has the option to include the column name. Therefore, the leading element in this selection is often (not always) alphabetic. Might this be an operative factor in the problem?

===============================

As per Michal's most recent response, I tried the following, but the problem still persists.

[image]

[image]

Any further assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right and I deleted my "answer" as I was completely wrong.  Puzzling.

Comment: What about just looping thru each cell of the range instead?  That seems to work for me without rounding the values and presercing the original formatting, something like     For Each cll In Range(str)
       Cells(cll.Rows, 11).Value2 = cll.Value2
    Next

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's going to suit your needs but it seems to work:

```
Option Base 1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim y0() As Double
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(RefEdit1)

    ReDim y0(rng.Count)

    For a = 1 To rng.Count
       y0(a) = rng.Item(a)
    Next

    Range("H2").Resize(rng.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(y0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Michal, Thank you for  your response. I edited the original question to include some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found that using the .Value2 property instead of .Value addressed this issue:

[image]